# Should the "e" in "'ello 'ello 'ello" be capital at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence, capitalization

If the the sentence is started with "'ello 'ello 'ello" should the "e" at the beginning be capital or should I count the omitted "H" still and have it lower case? Because I don't want to be ungrammatical as well as being arrested for impersonating a police officer...

Comment: That would be the [Grammar Police](http://www.makealivingwriting.com/4-reasons-grammar-police-make-terrible-writers/) (better known as the [Grammar Nazis](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Grammar_Nazi) :)

Comment: I vote most definitely for capitalisation. But don't forget the apostrophe. *'Ello, 'ello, 'ello, what 'ave we got 'ere* said Nacker of the Yard.